# Switching career from .net to Salesforce developer

Tags: developer

I have more than 6 years of experiance in .Net and I have done a training in Salesforce and I am trying to get Salesforce certified (DEV 401).But I don't have any experiance in Salesforce development.
Is it enough to have certification to get Salesforce development job and will I get more salary package than my current salary package is since I have 6 years of experiance in .Net technologies?

Comment: If you have 6 years experiEnce in changing oil filter on your car, doesn't mean that you can become a Mechanic by doing 1 day course and run a million dollar business...

Answer (score 1):

When I started to work with Salesforce, I had 8 years web development experience. Now, after 3 years of Salesforce experience I can say that it takes at least 1 year for it to get familiar to the subject. And yes, here I get more salary as Salesforce developer (about 35%) than in the Web Development. It is important but (at the moment) is not critical to have a certification. Nevertheless, I think it is very good to have the certification. In your place I would do it (for example i am on my way to [DEV401](http://certification.salesforce.com/developers)).